# PGFplot shrinks after I add it the main TeX document with standalone package. What should I do?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I would like to ask question concerning usage of PGFplots package (LaTeX). I have this problems: after inserting tex file using standalone package in my main document, part of pgfplot shrinks and font becomes very big in it. What You can recomend me to do with this problems? As for font it is possible to solve, if  in preabmle set:

```
\font=\footnotesize
```

I think there should be another way to work in out.

But my main concern is this shrinking of pgfplot.

Part of main document:

```
   ...
 \begin{figure}[h]
    \addtocounter{totalfigures}{1}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[mode=tex,width=\linewidth]{figures/test_pgf}
    \caption{Scheme for sub-pico second laser set-up.}
    \label{fig:fs-set-up}
    \end{figure}
...
```

My standalone file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french,russian]{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,shadows,calc,intersections}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}

\tikzset{
%Define standard arrow tip
>=stealth'
}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
font=\normalfont,
line width=1 pt,
tick style={line width=.6pt}}}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
        group size=1 by 2,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        xticklabels at=edge bottom,
        vertical sep=12pt
    },
    xmin=-8,
   xlabel={$\rm Delay\:time, \mu s$},
    ]
\nextgroupplot[
ymin=0,
ymax=1.02,
enlargelimits=false,
ylabel={$\rm Norm.\: luminescenece, a.u.$},
ylabel absolute,
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
legend style={draw=none},
legend pos=outer north east,
]
\addplot[black,mark=*,mark size=1pt] table [x index=0,y index=1] {test.dat};
\addplot[red,mark=x,mark size=0.2pt] table[x index=2, y index=3] {test.dat};
\legend {$d=1$,$Fit$}
\nextgroupplot[
ymax=0.011,
ymin=-.011,
enlargelimits=false,
ylabel={$\rm Residuals$},
ylabel absolute,
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=1,
height=3cm,
]
\addplot[black,mark=*,mark size=1pt] table [x index=0,y index=4] {test.dat};
\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Finally this is what I got:

[image: Problem]

P.S.

If I compile standalone TeX file plot looks fine, font is OK.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! You're probably not including `\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9}` in your main document. The cleanest solution would be to add `width=8cm` to the `axis` options in your `standalone` document.

Comment: That is true. Thank You.It helped to solve shrinking problem? But what shoud I do with font problems?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is, because you're not including the preamble of your main document. Could you please try to construct a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. the smallest example document that is needed to reproduce the problem (don't include all those libraries, or the `babel` package, for instance).

Comment: I did minimal working example, And it works as it should. It means that probably my other packages and document class {disser} fight with each other?

Comment: Typically, the best way to build a minimal working example that still reproduces the error is to start with the full document, and then remove package by package until the error goes away. That way, you can narrow your preamble down to the conflicting packages.

Comment: Old question, i know. Do you solved the problematic behaviour? To reproduce the problem easily test.dat is missing ( you could use `\begin{filecontents}`).